# Creating netCDF files for each value in a timeseries

Tags: r, raster, netcat

I have a timeseries data for streamflow for a specific location in the projected coordinate system (692662.97,4156787.11). And I also have a raster map with the information below:

```
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 1136, 624, 708864  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 9.369195, 9.369195  (x, y)
extent     : 687763.9, 693610.3, 4151329, 4161972  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : NA 
source     : case01.dem 
names      : case01
```

And the time series is like this:

```
        Time     value
1 0.00000000  226.5348
2 0.01666667  566.3369
3 0.03333333 3964.3586
4 0.05000000 5097.0325
5 0.06666667 6088.1221
6 0.08333333 7928.7172
```

and my data is:

```
 df <- data.frame(Time = c(0, 0.016666667, 0.033333333, 0.05, 0.066666667, 0.083333333, 0.1, 0.116666667, 0.133333333, 0.15),
                     value = c(226.534776, 566.33694, 3964.35858, 5097.03246, 6088.122105, 7928.71716, 8183.568783, 8070.301395, 7928.71716, 7702.182384))
```

So, as output I want to have 6 different matrices (or nc file) with a 1136x624 dimension, and each file will show these values for the specific cell (692662.97,4156787.11) in the raster map.